# Where store configuration mangopay?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mangopay

I want add mangopay payment system for received money from users.

Where need I add configuration in project?

## configuration

```
MangoPay.configure do |c|
  c.preproduction = true
  c.client_id = 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
  c.client_passphrase = 'YOUR_CLIENT_PASSWORD'
end
```

And maybe can who show examples project ruby on rails with using mangopay?

Thank for advance

Comment: I'd probably put it in an initializer, using environment variables for client id and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, a place to store library configurations would be in the initializer.

You should create a `config/initializers/mangopay.rb` and dump your configuration there.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have any project utilizing Mangopay with Ruby. But I'm sure there are resources online that you could follow.